# Simulation Data Not Plotting Correct on [0,1] Interval

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to plot 2 functions on the interval [0, 1]. One function works, but the one I use with simulation data does not.

```
\documentclass[8pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,shapes.multipart}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,calc}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
 \usepackage{verbatim}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot[blue,domain=0:.95] {ln(1000000)/((1-x))};
\addplot[smooth,domain=0:.95] 
(0.01,15.4936011731625) -- 
(0.05,16.1972063938156) -- 
(0.1,15.6307188495994) -- 
(0.15,15.8221184986178) -- 
(0.2,17.3298915610067) -- 
(0.35,28.2033991515636) -- 
(0.4,22.9307031580538) -- 
(0.45,24.6029702750966) -- 
(0.5,24.9720082713757) -- 
(0.55,28.3029688145034) -- 
(0.6,31.5953977632453) -- 
(0.65,33.9497355091153) -- 
(0.7,45.5851026929449) -- 
(0.75,56.294973153621) -- 
(0.8,63.6406904051546) -- 
(0.85,65.5148971946328) -- 
(0.9,117.04824508907) -- 
(0.95,174.020252958231)  ;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your format for providing the data is wrong: You can either use `\addplot [...] coordinates {(...) (...) (...)};` (no dashes between the coordinates), or even better, provide a data table using

```
\addplot [...] table {
x0 y0
x1 y1
x2 y2
};
```

Note that the `domain` key has no effect when you're plotting data from coordinates or tables, it only applies when you're plotting a function.

[image]

So either

```
\documentclass[8pt]{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot[blue,domain=0:0.95] {ln(1000000)/((1-x))};
\addplot[smooth] coordinates {
(0.01,15.4936011731625) 
(0.05,16.1972063938156) 
(0.1,15.6307188495994) 
(0.15,15.8221184986178) 
(0.2,17.3298915610067) 
(0.35,28.2033991515636) 
(0.4,22.9307031580538) 
(0.45,24.6029702750966) 
(0.5,24.9720082713757) 
(0.55,28.3029688145034) 
(0.6,31.5953977632453) 
(0.65,33.9497355091153) 
(0.7,45.5851026929449) 
(0.75,56.294973153621) 
(0.8,63.6406904051546) 
(0.85,65.5148971946328) 
(0.9,117.04824508907) 
(0.95,174.020252958231)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

or

```
\documentclass[8pt]{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot[blue,domain=0:0.95] {ln(1000000)/((1-x))};
\addplot[smooth] table{
0.01 15.4936011731625 
0.05 16.1972063938156 
0.1  15.6307188495994 
0.15 15.8221184986178 
0.2  17.3298915610067 
0.35 28.2033991515636 
0.4  22.9307031580538 
0.45 24.6029702750966 
0.5  24.9720082713757 
0.55 28.3029688145034 
0.6  31.5953977632453
0.65 33.9497355091153 
0.7  45.5851026929449
0.75 56.294973153621
0.8  63.6406904051546
0.85 65.5148971946328 
0.9  117.04824508907
0.95 174.020252958231
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is better - thanks - But, how do I get the plot to be really smooth - For instance, when I plot the same data in Excel, I get a nice, much smoother curve.

Comment: @PierreMFiorini: Do you mean the blue plot? Add `smooth` to the options, and/or increase the sample size by setting `samples=50` or `samples=100`.